# Regex formula for all text including inside HTML tags, but not in 'a' tags

Tags: .net, regex

I am struggling with the formula to replace text in a string, while looking in all tags apart from 'a' tags (links).

This is my current formula:

`\b(?<!-)text\b(?<!<[^<>]*)(?!-|[^<>]*>)`

Example, I would like to replace only the instances of 'text' outside of the 'a' tag, so within the 'p' and 'li' tags:

```
<p>
    Some text here. <a href="#">Some more text</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Other text</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

It must also match on whole words including dashes, which the formula currently does successfully. It also (I believe) doesn't replace anything within the tags themselves, ie:

```
<li class="text">here some text</li>
```

It would not replace the 'text' in the class name.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to do that by regex at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What about text in a different (say `li`) tag _inside_ an `a` tag?

Comment: Anything inside an a tag, even nested, should be ignored @MetaColon

Comment: On which kind of Regex is your formula based? On https://regex101.com/ there's an error for PCRE, ECMAScript, Python and Golang (so basically for every flavor).

Comment: But intuitively it seems to me that this is beyond the scope of regular languages, as you'd have to know how deeply nested you are, to be sure that you're outside of all `a` tags. I guess this shouldn't be a problem, as you'll rarely have nested `a` tags, but you should be aware of the non-perfect solution then

Comment: I use this @MetaColon: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: The only scenario would be a tags within other tags, not the other way around, ie there will never be a ul/li within an a tag, for example. Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

This formula should do what you want:

```
(?:\A|<\/a>)(?:[^<]|<[^a])*?(text)
```

The results of the match (meaning *text* in this case) are stored in the corresponding group (1) of the match. Note however, that this does fail for example if there are links inside the link, as mentioned in the comments, or if you have weird strings inside your document. Also note that this only matches up to the first match in an area outside of a link - if you want to replace something, you'll have to run the expression multiple times. If you only have a maximum of 2 occurances of *text* in such an area, you can combine this query with this one:

```
(?:\A|<\/a>)(?:[^<]|<[^a])*(text)
```

which matches the last *text*.

I'm aware this isn't an optimal solution, so I'm open to improvement suggestions. However, I'm not sure whether Regex is the best solution here (as Yunnosch pointed out), as Regex does only have a limited power (it is, after all, a type-3 grammar).

Let me explain the formula:

- `(?:\A|<\/a>)` match either the start of the input or the end of a link
- `(?:[^<]|<[^a])*` match everything that is not an indication of a tag, or - if so - if it's at least not the start of a link
- `?` match as little as possible (hence the first match)
- `(text)` match the actual text (and save it in the group)

You can access the groups for example by using `$1` or `/1`, depending on your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't seem to be working - testing with the regexstorm link I sent it's highlighting more than just 'text' - when using "hello text here" it highlights "hello text", and I think it is just going from the beginning of the string

Comment: @Benjo it's highlighting more, because the relevant part (text) is in the group. As regular languages are (way) less powerful then context sensitive languages, I don't think it's possible otherwise. You should still be able to solve whatever problem you have with this approach though.

Comment: @Benjo note that the _table_ option in your link is useful for seeing this (especially the last column of the table)